# Get million record from django with queryset is slow

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to iterate all the objects of a table(Post)
I am using below code:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
for post in posts:
   process_post(post)
```

`process_post` is a celery task which will run in background and its not updating post.But the problem I am having is Post table has 1 million records.This is not one time job.I am running it daily.

```
for post in posts
```

In above line, Query is called which fetches all the data from DB in one go.

How can I improve its performance?
Is there any way by which data is fetched in batches?

Comment: is `process_post` an  update method?

Comment: Use [`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator). If it still results in too much memory consumption you may want to consider using database-side cursor.

Comment: Data *is* fetched in batches by Django. Actually, the default behavior is to load everything. But loading rows as python objects is a slow process, if you only have simple processing to do, I suggest you use `values()` and `update()`, or even `update()` alone if possible. ... and make that processing a custom manager or queryset method.

Comment: select_related() and prefetch_related() have been very useful for me for optimizing django queries. This post may be helpful : http://bookofstranger.com/optimizing-django-orm-queries-for-best-performance/

Comment: @Surajano process_post is a celery task which will run in background and its not updating post

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think if we use iterator it will not improve the performance because fetching of data from DB will be in one go.Iterator will only increase performance loop

Comment: @spectras using values() will return the only specific columns But it will return specific columns of all the rows in one go.

Comment: @Himanshudua> well, sure, but unless you need most columns, loading only those you need saves both time and memory. You can also use `values_list`, which avoids creating a model instance, for every row, saving a lot of time and memory. My point being: not fetching all data in one go will save you memory but not time. To save time you must cut down on Django-side processing, and `values()` and `values_list()` are excellent ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your own `iterator`. For Example, say `1 million` records.

```
count = Post.objects.all().count() #1 million
chunk_size = 1000   
for i in range(0, count, chunk_size):
    posts = Post.objects.all()[i:i+chunk_size]
    for post in posts:
        process_post(post)
```

Slicing on queryset will play `LIMIT`,  `OFFSET` usages. Query can decrease as per `chunk_size` increase where as memory usage also increase. Optimize it for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

My First Suggestion would be use select_related or prefetch_related. Go through the documentation of django and learn about it, It should fix your problem. But as you have said that you have some millions of records for that table. Iterating through those will always be a costly business. The best solution is to go for stored procedure if the process_post method is taking time. You can achieve your goal with only one request to your db instead of millions of db calls in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Django is not used for process the data. this is just framework for making API and ORM for frontend.**

you can limit process depending on your memory and database like
obj = post.objects.all()[30000] etc or 50000

if you want to show in HTML front end use pagination

if you want process on backend don't use Django ORM. in database make materlized view and database job (this is very easy in oracle database)